# Rails routes on query string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm new to Ruby on rails. Now I have a search form in my homepage. When I enter something (like abc) in the form and submit, I would like the page to call my action `info` in my controller `search`. How should I configure the routes?

The current url is `~/info/?utf8=%E2%9C%93&location=berkeley&commit=submi`t

```
<div id='search_form'>
<%= form_tag('info/',method: "get") do %>
<%= text_field_tag('location', @location, :size => 30) %> 
<%= submit_tag "submit",  class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your routes file:

```
get '/info', to: "search#info", as: 'search_info'
```

This gives you `search_info_path` and you can use it in your `form_for` declaration as follows:

```
<%= form_tag(search_info_path, method: "get") do %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= form_tag some_path, method: "get" do %>
<%= text_field_tag('location', @location, :size => 30) %> 
<%= submit_tag "submit",  class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

You can use path helper in you form_tag that leads to your controller.

i think this is wrong `('info/',method: "get")`

run `rake routes` for look helper`s